# Remove Scrollsbar from Widget

Tags: iframe, scrollbar, eventbrite

I have a website where I use an Eventbrite Widget to checkout a page on my website.

It turns out that when running the script, the iframe, especially on cell phones, does not show the entire checkout. Scrollsbar appears to scroll and see some information.

It turns out that I would like to remove these scrollsbars, because some users don't bother to scroll them down  and end up not filling in some data and not being able to proceed with the purchase.

The code I have is this:

I tried a height on the div, but it didn't work.

```
type her<div id="eventbrite-widget-container-489731288460" style="display: block; height: 100%;"></div>
<p>
<script src="https://www.eventbrite.com.br/static/widgets/eb_widgets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var exampleCallback = function() {
       console.log('Order complete!');
};
window.EBWidgets.createWidget({
// Required
widgetType: 'checkout',
eventId: '489731288460',
iframeContainerId: 'eventbrite-widget-container-489731288460',
// Optional
iframeContainerHeight: 900, // Widget height in pixels. Defaults to a minimum of 425px if not provided
onOrderComplete: exampleCallback // Method called when an order has successfully completed
});
</script>e
```

I also put the iframeContainerHeight: 900, but on the cell phone the scrollbar continues to appear

If anyone knows how to solve it, I'm grateful.

Remove eventbrite iframe scrollbar